# How to run a program from within a C program using Windows ShellExecute

Tags: shellexecute

I'm trying to run a program called simple.exe from my C program running under Windows 10.
Program simple.exe uses no parameters and is passing nothing back.  Can I just use:

ShellExecute("C:\somewhere\simple.exe")

My C program is a basic Windows program.

Thankyou.

Comment: You don't need `ShellExecute`, just use `system()` instead, which is part of the C standard library.

Comment: so something like this should work in C? system("simple.exe");

Comment: Yes that would work, but only if `simple.exe` is in your process’ `PATH`. Note that you *can* specify a fully-qualified file name too (just don’t forget to escape the backslashes).